# pandas: write hdf with python2.7 and read it with python3.7

Tags: python, pandas, hdf

I have a dataframe which its values include arrays, I wrote it to hdf in python2.7 and want to read it in python3.7 - and get an UnicodeDecodeError.
I followed this issue https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/17540 , but couldn't implement the suggested solutions:

- save with `format='table` is impossible for object types.
- save with `encoding='utf-8'` worked, but reading the hdf raise: `TypeError: lookup() argument must be str, not numpy.bytes_`

Is there any other solution?

Comment: Maybe you could use `format='table'` if you convert your object types to one of the [types supported by PyTables](https://www.pytables.org/usersguide/datatypes.html)? What kind of object types are you working with?

Comment: @NickODell the object type is ```numpy.ndarray``` and it seems not supported in format table. See [https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/20440]

Answer (score 0):

You could use `format='table'` if you save the numpy arrays under a separate key. Here's an example of how to do this.

Start by creating an example dataset. I've only tested this with 1d and 2d arrays, but it should work for any dimension. I also import h5py so I can directly read/write hdf5 files.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import h5py

df = pd.DataFrame({'time': [0, 1, 2], 'signal':[np.array([1, 2, 3], dtype='int'),
                                                np.array([2, 0, 1], dtype='int'),
                                                np.array([3, 3, 4], dtype='int')],
                                      'signal2':[np.array([2, 3, 4], dtype='int'),
                                                np.array([1, 1, 1], dtype='int'),
                                                np.array([2, 2, 2], dtype='int')]})
```

Next, define the save function. This code visits each cell in the columns which cannot be correctly encoded, and saves each one under a different key. (Note: this assumes that you have a unique index.)

```py
def save(df, filename, cols_to_save_separately):
    with h5py.File(filename, "w") as f:
        for col in cols_to_save_separately:
            for i, array in df[col].iteritems():
                dataset_key = f"{col}_{i}"
                f.create_dataset(dataset_key, data=array)
    for col in cols_to_save_separately:
        df = df.drop(col, axis=1)
    df.to_hdf(filename, key='tab', mode='a', format='table',
                 data_columns=['time'])
```

Do the reverse to load the file.

```py
def read(filename, cols_to_save_separately):
    new_df = pd.read_hdf(filename, key='tab')
    with h5py.File(filename, "r") as f:
        for col in cols_to_save_separately:
            new_df[col] = pd.Series([f[f"{col}_{i}"][:] for i in new_df.index])
    return new_df
```

Here's an example of how to use this code. We remove columns signal and signal2, since those contain the arrays. The time column can be left alone.

```py
print("Prior to save")
print(df)
save(df, 'events.h5', cols_to_save_separately=['signal', 'signal2'])
print("After save")
print(read('events.h5', cols_to_save_separately=['signal', 'signal2']))
```

This produces the following output:

```
Prior to save
   time     signal    signal2
0     0  [1, 2, 3]  [2, 3, 4]
1     1  [2, 0, 1]  [1, 1, 1]
2     2  [3, 3, 4]  [2, 2, 2]
After save
   time     signal    signal2
0     0  [1, 2, 3]  [2, 3, 4]
1     1  [2, 0, 1]  [1, 1, 1]
2     2  [3, 3, 4]  [2, 2, 2]
```